# Oracle Sql select problem with remove data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an sql query with this structure

```
EMPNO
FIRSTNME
MNGNO
```

and sample data

is

```
20 AA 1
2  BB 30
3  CC 20
```

my select query is when EMPNO is equal to MNGNO remove both records from the select and the result will be only

```
2  BB 30
```

Comment: Do you mean _EMPNO is equal to **any** MNGNO_?

Comment: Hi - you haven’t actually asked a question and your question needs to show what you’ve attempted so far

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option, for sample data

```
SQL> with test (empno, firstname, mngno) as
  2    (select 20, 'AA',  1 from dual union all
  3     select  2, 'BB', 30 from dual union all
  4     select  3, 'CC', 20 from dual
  5    )
```

Query:

```
  6  select a.*
  7  from test a
  8  where not exists (select null
  9                    from test b
 10                    where b.mngno = a.empno)
 11    and not exists (select null
 12                    from test c
 13                    where c.empno = a.mngno);

     EMPNO FIRSTNAME       MNGNO
---------- ---------- ----------
         2 BB                 30

SQL>
```

Or simpler

```
  6  select a.*
  7  from test a
  8  where not exists (select null
  9                    from test b
 10                    where b.mngno = a.empno
 11                       or b.empno = a.mngno);

     EMPNO FIRSTNAME       MNGNO
---------- ---------- ----------
         2 BB                 30

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to join the table to itself and look for non-matches:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM   table_name t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t2
       ON t1.empno = t2.mngno
       OR t1.mngno = t2.empno
WHERE  t2.empno IS NULL;
```

or, using only a single table scan:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LEVEL = 1
AND    CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR empno = mngno
OR     PRIOR mngno = empno;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (EMPNO, FIRSTNME, MNGNO) AS
  SELECT 20, 'AA',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,  'BB', 30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,  'CC', 20 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

| EMPNO | FIRSTNME | MNGNO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | BB | 30 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VDIJxFh2)